# How do I make an array have size of a value inputted by a user? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

Here is what I am basically trying to do

```
cout<<"Enter size of array"<<endl;
cin>>size;

int my_array[size];
```

The compiler complains that size must be constant.

Comment: instead of vector you can use dynamic array as follows
int* my_array=new int[size];

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, arrays must have constant size. You'll want a dynamic array:

```
std::vector<int>(size);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very speedy reply

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the new keyword here to allocate memory dynamically just modify your code like this and it should be fine

int *my_array;

```
 cout<<"Enter size of array"<<endl;
 cin>>size;
 my_array=new int[size];
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::vector`, use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` or at least do `delete []`.